# Get function name in KornShell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I'd like to get the function name from within the function, for logging purposes.

KornShell (ksh) function:

```
foo ()
{
    echo "get_function_name some useful output"
}
```

Is there anything similar to `$0`, which returns the script name within scripts, but which instead provides a function's name?

Comment: Off-topic to this question: for bash, use the [FUNCNAME](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-FUNCNAME-193) array variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you define the function with the `function` keyword, then `$0` is the function name:

```
$ function foo {
>     echo "$0"
> }
$ foo
foo
```

(Tested in pdksh.)

Comment: perfect, works fine! what are the main pros/cons of using keyword function? At my place people seem to use ksh88 (hard to tell for sure), but I didn't see a single function keyword within scripts

Comment: @Dima: `function` makes this a Korn shell function, which has a `$0`. The other form exists for System V/POSIX compatibility.

Answer (score 6):

> [...] what are the main pros/cons of using keyword function?

Main pro is that "typeset myvar=abc" inside the function is now a local variable, with no possible side effects outside the function.  This makes KSH noticeably safer for large shell scripts.  Main con is, perhaps, the non-POSIX syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Use the ksh "function foo ..." form:

```
$ cat foo1
#!/bin/ksh
foo3() { echo "\$0=$0"; }
function foo2 { echo "\$0=$0"; }
foo2
foo3
$ ./foo1
$0=foo2
$0=./foo1
```

Answer (score 0):

The function below seems to get its name in both Bash and ksh:

```
# ksh or bash
function foo {
  local myname="${FUNCNAME[0]:-$0}"
  echo "$myname"
}
# test
foo
# ...
```